# Is there a mathematics journal that publishes colour diagrams for free?

Tags: publications, mathematics

I have a paper with colour diagrams that I wouldn't like to convert to grayscale for publication. I think colour greatly helps to understand some complicated patterns. I know most journals accept colour pictures upon payment, but I'm not willing to pay for letting others publish my own work and get benefit out of it. Forum Mathematicum is a nice journal which publishes colour pictures for free, but I recently published a paper there and wouldn't like to repeat. Do you know of any other nice options? The paper is on algebraic topology bordering with quantum algebra.

Comment: In all journals I know, the restriction to grayscale (or extra costs for colour) is only for the printed version – which hardly anybody reads anymore. In the digitial versions, all graphics are coloured as long as they have been submitted as such.

Comment: Let me say that -- although in general I certainly do believe that most contemporary journals practice highway robbery of one form or another -- I do in fact believe that printing things in colo(u)r is more expensive.  Someone needs to absorb this extra cost; if not the author then it must be (right?) the readers.  I don't blame you for not wanting to pay for it yourself, but framing it as you versus the journal strikes me as not necessarily being accurate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Quantum Topology prints diagrams in color.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys. @Wrzlprmft the point is that in the text I refer to the red part or the blue part of this and that picture. This is why I wouldn't like even the printed version to be without colours.

Comment: You can try with "A full colour version of Figure~1 is available online on arXiv.org in the e-print version of this paper [37]." I've gotten away with a similar sentence on a Springer journal.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni thanks, Federico, not a bad idea, still I'd like to try to get an optimal solution, at the risk of you all calling me perfectionist.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark printing colours is of course more expensive than grayscale, but the costs are absorved by far with journal prices *with current prices* (there will always be exceptions, but I'm certain this is the case for most journals).

Comment: You might check if AGT prints in color. It's primarily an electronic journal, but they do print out hard copies for some subscribers.

Comment: You can write _in a way visible from the metadata/free sample_ that a full-colour preprint version available at arXiv:... That way people also get to know where they can get a free copy if they or their institution don't subscribe.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I appreciate all your comments, but explanatory sentences about where the reader can find real colour pictures is not a good alternative. There are more than 10 colour figures and references to (colours in) them are constant. I should have made this clearer. The sort of answers I'm looking for are those of Noah Snyder and David Robers, however QT is too low-dimensional for this paper and I have kind of overworked AGT during the last years, although I will think about trying to repeat, sure.

Comment: Do you insist on a journal that has a print version? There are certainly electronic journals where this would not arise.

Comment: @nateeldredge no, electronic journals are fine, you'll see above that I've considered a couple of them, but the paper doesn't fully fit for scientific reasons. Can you please suggest other journals? Thanks!

Comment: How about SIGMA (http://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/about.html) which is online only?

Comment: @just-learning thanks! Unfortunately the paper is not within the scope of the journal.

Comment: Regardless of how the paper is published, I think it's best to ensure it is _possible_ to understand the pictures in greyscale. There will always be people viewing it that way - on paper or ebook reader, or because they are colour blind. I know of a paper that has a statement of the form 'when viewed in greyscale, colour X appears darker than colour Y'.

Comment: To add to @JessicaB 's comment, I have found [this guide](http://www.lighthouse.org/accessibility/design/accessible-print-design/effective-color-contrast) useful when thinking about how the document is seen by those with reduced sight.

Comment: @JessicaB and WillieWong you're absolutely right, thanks. I'll take into consideration your indications in order to choose the colors.

Comment: The important thing that were not covered in the comments yet is that many reviewers will print your article on their greyscale printer for the review. If Figures will be hard to understand in greyscale, your chances for rejection increase:)

Answer (score -11):

I would recommend you to publish on `arXiv.org` (http://arxiv.org). It's a very solid online publication outlet, free, **open access** and especially popular in mathematics and other hard science disciplines. Liberal guidelines with no mentioning of restrictions in terms of color.

Comment: Isn't arXiv a preprint archive? OP is looking for a journal, online or printed publishing.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: I wouldn't call arXiv.org a "preprint archive", even if it's considered as one by most people. Firstly, because nowadays the line between traditional publishing and self-publishing is blurring rapidly. Secondly, because one might decide to publish own work on arXiv and not anywhere else after that. In this case, the term "preprint" doesn't apply, in my opinion.

Comment: People might choose to publish only on arXiv, but they will rarely be considered serious researchers by the rest of the community.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I respectfully disagree. As an example, consider Russian mathematician Grigori Perelman (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Perelman), who became famous for solving the Poincaré conjecture problem and consequently has been awarded Fields Medal (his controversial nonacceptance of it is irrelevant here). He published his work as a series of papers on arXiv and AFAIK no other publications in peer-reviewed outlets were made by him. Moreover, two of the three groups of scientists (from well-respected universities), who verified his proof, posted their work on arXiv as well.

Comment: I said rarely, not never. Perelman is not the norm, and if most people did things that way they would never get any career.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I understand, but even not considering "ouliers", such as Perelman, I clearly see trend that places less emphasis on where one publishes and more on the essence and quality of the work itself. I expect this trend to be even more pronounced along with emerging movements for open data, open access and open science.

Comment: Whether it's a preprint service or not isn't really relevant; it's *definitely* not a journal, and that's what the question asks for.

Comment: There might be a trend that the precise journal matters less. But I have not seen any sort of trend away from peer-review.

Comment: @ff524: Sometimes you need to read between the lines. While the question formally is indeed focused on journals, the question "tone" and the word "options" indicated to me that the OP might be open to suggestions of options beyond the standard ones. Hence my answer. Despite all the negativity of some people here, the acceptance of my answer by the OP suggests that he is pretty happy with it. And, ultimately, it's all that matters. Have a nice day!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Fair enough.